Does $ f(x, X) \overset{D}{=}h_1(x) + h_2(X)$ imply that $f$ is additive?
Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with full support on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be a continuous function such that there exist $h_1, h_2$ functions satisfying
$$
f(x, X) \overset{D}{=}h_1(x) + h_2(X), \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,for\,\,all\,\,\,x\in\mathbb{R}. 
$$
Does this necessary mean that there exist $\tilde{h}_1, \tilde{h}_2$ functions satisfying
$$
f(x, y) \overset{}{=}\tilde{h}_1(x) + \tilde{h}_2(y), \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,for\,\,all\,\,\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}?
$$
Edit: Michael showed a valid counterexample. However it is the periodicity of $f$ that makes the counterexample exist. What is a non-trivial assumption of $f$ that makes the statement valid? If $f$ is Non-periodic? Surjective? Bijective?

Please avoid titles that consist of nothing but mathjax code, as they break some navigational shortcuts.

sorry, I will have it in mind next time

Thank you.${}{}{}$

The implication holds if

A: for any $x$, $f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing and continuous in $y$ (or for any $x$, $f(x,y)$ is strictly decreasing and continuous in $y$).

Note that the assumption on continuity of $f$ made in the OP is stronger than what we actually require (continuity of $f$ in $x$ is not required).

The proof is only presented for the case that $f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing in $y$ (the proof for the other case is similar).
From $f(x,X)\sim h_1(x)+h_2(X), \, \forall x$, it follows that

B: $g(x,X) \sim g(x',X)$ has the same distribution for any $x, x'$

where we define $$g(x,y)=f(x,y)-h_1(x).$$
Moreover, as $X$ has full support, we have

C: $F_X$ is strictly increasing.

Hence, for any $x$, $g(x,y)$ is continuous and strictly increasing in $y$. This allows the inverse of $g(x,y)$ with respect to $y$, denoted by $k_x$, to exist for any $x$.
Then, from B, one can see that for any $a\in \mathbb R$ with $\small 0<\mathbb P \left (g(x,X) \le a \right)<1$, the following probability
$$\mathbb P \left (g(x,X) \le a \right)=\mathbb P \left (X \le k_x (a) \right)=F_X(k_x (a)), \, \forall x$$
is independent of $x$. Now from C, it follows that $k_x(a)$ must be independent of $x$, which implies $g(x,y)=h_3(y)$ for some function $h_3(y)$. Indeed, as $k_x(a)$ does not depend on $x$, from the equivalence $$y=k_x(a) \Leftrightarrow g(x,y)=a,$$ it follows that for any fixed $y$, $g(x,y)=g(x',y)$ for all $x,x'$, so for any fixed $y$, $g(x,y)$ is a constant function, denoted by $h_3(y)$. Hence, we have $$f(x, y) =h_1(x) + h_3(y).$$
Q.E.D.

PS: Note that $h_3(y)$ may differ from $h_2(y)$; i.e., it is possible that $$f(x,y)-h_1(x)\neq h_2(y).$$ As a counterexample, let us consider $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $$f(x,y)=-\log \Phi(y)+h_1(x)$$ $$h_2(y)=-\log \left (1-\Phi(y) \right)$$
where $f(x,y)$ is strictly decreasing in $y$. Then, we have $$f(x,X)-h_1(x) \sim h_2(X) \sim \mathcal {Exp} (1), \, \forall x,$$ but $f(x,y)-h_1(x)\neq h_2(y)$.

Thanks for the answer. You lost me at 'the above is possible only if $g(x,y) = h_3(y)$'. Why? Also, does the inverse have to exist? and also, C: $F_X$ is strictly increasing is automatically true since $X$ has full support.

@AlbertParadek Under A, $g(x,y)$ is strictly increasing, and also continuous, so for each $x$, the invers of $g(x,y)$ with respect to $y$ exists. If $F_X$ is always strictly increasing, you can easily see for any $a$ for which we have $g(x,y)=a$ for some $y$, $k_x(a)$ needs to be independent of $x$.

Okay, so $P(g(x, X)\leq a) = \psi(a)$ for some function $\psi$. Why does this imply that $g(x, y) = h_3(y)?$ Take for instance the example from Michael`s answer. Then $g(x, Y)$ has the same distribution for every $x$ but $g$ can not be written as $g(x, y) = h_3(y)$

It follows from the fact that $F_X(k_x (a))$ is constant for all $x$ (holds because of B), so  $k_x (a)$ needs to be a constant function for any $a$ that can be generated by some $y$, becuase of C. Michael's function $g$ cannot be used here as it is not a strictly monotone function of $y$.

Amir, your ideas are good but your argumentation is a bit sloppy. Assumptions B, C are true without assuming them. You claim $F_X(k_x(a))$ is increasing in $x$, which need not be true, but is not needed in your argument. Details about inverses not necessarily existing when we have nondecreasing, versus strictly increasing, are not provided.

If $f$, $h_1$ are continuous and $f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing in $y$ for each $x$, then $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-h_1(x)$ is continuous and strictly increasing in $y$ for each $x$ and the inverse
$k_x(a)$ makes sense and is also strictly increasing in $a$. So B means $P[g(x,X)\leq a]$ does not depend on $x$, which means $F_X(k_x(a))$ does not depend on $x$, which by C means $k_x(a)$ does not depend on $x$. [I believe this eventually implies $g(x,y)$ does not depend on $x$.] [Perhaps this can be generalized to replace "strictly increasing" with "nondecreasing" and "continuous" with "measurable."]

@Michael thanks for your kind support! Actually, I did not assume B or C, I just said we had them (from the hypothesis I meant here from what assumed in the OP).  $F_X(k_x (a))$ is a strictly increasing continuous function of $k_x (a)$ ($x$ was a typo). Thanks for your concluding statement! If $f(x,y)$ is only increasing in $y$, then $f(x,X)$ can be a non-contiuous random variable, so we cannot prove $h_1$ is a continouse function.

@Michael I just updated the answer. I realized that the continuity of $h_1$ is not required. For any fixed $x$, $g(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$, which is enough to derive the inverse $k_x$ under A.

@AlbertParadek I just updated the answer. Is there any part that needs more clarification?

Sounds good. Suggestions: You may want to edit by removing the ambiguous term "strictly monotone," removing the unusual "WLOG" (why is "without loss of generality" there?), restructuring to clarify what your assumptions are (I think just that $f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing and continuous in $y$ for each $x$) and make the statements B, C more clear that they are consequences rather than assumptions themselves. As it is, I think the ideas are correct but it is hard to follow.  It may also help to remove the tangential point about the title.

@Michael Iwill  try to improve it using your comments. On your first suggestion: "strictly monotone" includes both "strictly increasing" and "strictly decreasing".

Then I would say "either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing." I tend to think of "monotonically increasing" as "nondecreasing" and I have no idea what "strictly monotone" means.

thanks a lot for the effort.  the answer looks correct,  although two things may need improvements: 1- all we need is the existence of the inverse k, right? we don't need the monotonicity (which implies the existence from Inverse function theorem). 2- is it trivial that if the inverse k does not depend on x, then g does not depend on x? i mean,  your if and only if équivalence is really if and only even if k is not monotone?

@AlbertParadek You are welcome! Regarding your two points 1- You may note that a continuous function is invertible if it is a one-to-one function iff it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. As $g$ is continuous, then invertibility and strict monotonicity are equivalent here. 2- The inverse of a continuous function is strictly increasing or decreasing. The given equivalence is actually the definition of the inverse function $k x$ here. I think you want to use full inverse (which is a multivalued function) and it branches, but analysis of the resulting probability seems difficult.

@Amir : Looks good (+1). You may want to add to Assumption A that, for given $x$, $f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing [and continuous] in $y$.  [I think the argument does not even require continuity in the $x$ dimension.]

@Michael Thank you!  Just considred your suggestion. I agree that continuty in $x$ is not required.

@AlbertParadek When $f$ is not continuous in $y$, assuming that $k_x$ exists for any $x$ is not enough as it may not preserve the order due to lack of monotonicity.  See here.

This is false.
Let $Y \sim N(0,1)$. Define the continuous function $F_Y(y) = P[Y\leq y]$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that
$$F_Y(Y) \sim \mbox{Uniform}(0,1)$$
Define the continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $h_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $h_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= \cos(2\pi F_Y(y) + x) \quad \forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\\
h_1(x) &= 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
h_2(y) &= \cos(2\pi F_Y(y)) \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
Then
$$ f(x,Y) = \cos(2\pi F_Y(Y) + x) \sim \cos(2\pi F_Y(Y)) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
where for random variables $A,B$, I use notation $A \sim B$ to mean $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution. In particular,
$$f(x,Y) \sim h_1(x) + h_2(Y) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
However, $f(x,y)$ does not have the form $\tilde{h}_1(x)+\tilde{h}_2(y)$.

Note that I spent most of my time trying to prove it was true. =)

Nice. Just out of curiosity, do you think it's true if $f(x,\cdot)$ is surjective for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Yes, this is correct answer. Yeah, I would be extremely interested in an assumption on $f$ that would make the statement valid

@user159517 : I don't know. Amir has now shown it works for $f(x,y)$ continuous and strictly increasing in $y$ for each fixed $x$. That assumption does not require surjectivity onto $\mathbb{R}$, but it ensures surjectivity onto an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ for each fixed $x$.

This is more like an idea to approach this problem, or a comment, but too long to be written in the comment box above.
If you could get a representation theorem to change equality in distribution for almost sure equality, the answer would be yes.
By definition, $X$ is a function $\Omega \to \mathbf{R}$ and you are assuming that if $P(X \in R) = 0$ then $R$ has empty interior. Therefore, $f(x,y) = h_1(x) + h_2(y)$ for all $y$ in the range of $X$, i.e., for $y \in X(\Omega).$ Since $P(X \in X(\Omega)^\complement) = 0,$ $X(\Omega)^\complement$ has empty interior. This entails that $ f(x,y) = h_1(x) + h_2(y)$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$ and $y$ outside a set with empty interior. Then, $h_2(y) = f(x,y) - h_1(x),$ and the right hand side does not depend on $x \in \mathbf{R}$ and defines a continuous function on $y \in \mathbf{R},$ so define $\tilde{h}_2(y)$ as this continuous extension of $h_2$ (extending it from a set with empty interior to $\mathbf{R},$ note such set is dense in $\mathbf{R}$).

Thanks for the comment. I agree that if the equality would be almost sure equality, then the statement would be correct.

There are a few clarifications needed for your assumptions.
The answer is yes if we assume that :

$h_2: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable. The point is that $h_2(y)$ is already defined for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and I made the additional measurability assumption.
$f(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
$X$ is defined on probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ and has density function $g$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure such that $g > 0$ everywhere. For example, $X$ can be normally distributed. Write $P_X$ for the distribution of $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Start by fixing temporarily an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition, $h_2(X) = f(x,X)-h_1(x)$. Let $N_x$ be the set of all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h_2(y) \neq f(x,y)-h_1(x)$. By assumption 1, $N_x$ is Lebesgue measurable. If $N_x$ has positive Lebesgue measure, then $P_X(N_x) = P \{X \in N_x\} > 0$, a direct contradiction. Therefore, $h_2(y) = f(x,y)-h_1(x)$ holds for every $y \in \mathbb{R}-N_x$. Note also that $N_x$ has empty interior by continuity of $X$.
If we do this procedure for $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, we get $h_2(y) = f(x_1,y)-h_1(x_1)=f(x_2,y)-h_1(x_2)$. If there exists $y \in N_{x_1}-N_{x_2}$, we are supposed to get $h_2(y) \neq f(x_1,y)-h_1(x_1)$ and $h_2(y) = f(x_2,y)-h_1(x_2)$, a contradiction. Therefore, $N_{x_1} = N_{x_2}$. We write $N$ in place of $N_x$ as we have removed the dependency.
To summerise, we have proved that $f(x,y)=h_1(x)+h_2(y)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $y \in \mathbb{R}-N$, where $N$ is Lebesgue measurable with Lebesgue measure zero. In particular, $h_2(y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}-N$.
Finally, extend $h_2$ to $\tilde{h_2}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
such that $\tilde{h_2}=h_2$ in $\mathbb{R}-N$ and $\tilde{h_2}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. Put $\tilde{h_1}(x,y)=f(x,y)-\tilde{h_2}(y)$. For every $y \in \mathbb{R}-N$, $\tilde{h_1}(x,y)=h_1(x)$. Given $y \in N$, let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. Choose $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq \mathbb{R}-N$ such that $y_n \to y$ as $n \to \infty$. This is possible as $N$ has empty interior. We see that:
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{h_1}(x,y) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\tilde{h_1}(x,y_n)
=\lim_{n \to \infty}h_1(x)=h_1(x)
\end{equation*}
So $\tilde{h_1}(x,y)$ does not depend on $y$. For any $y$, it equals constantly to $h_1(x)$. We have proved that there exists function $\tilde{h_2}(y)$ such that $f(x,y)=h_1(x)+\tilde{h_2}(y)$ for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. The proof is complete.

You lost me at "By definition, $h_2(X)=f(x,X)-h_1(x)$." This does not seem to be part of the "equal in distribution" definition.

Wait you mean they are equal in distribution? I thought it just means defined (pointwise) equal to that. Let me see if I can save this answer by altering parts of it.
